Sharing OpenGL textures across GtkGLAreas
I have multiple GtkGLAreas that I want to share OpenGL textures across. Is there any way to do this for GTK 3 or GTK 4? Using glGenTextures creates identical texture IDs for me, indicating the contexts aren't currently shared.
Alternatively, a way to reuse a single GdkGLContext across multiple GtkGLAreas is welcome too! This also solves my problem nicely.
